# How to calculate the Maurer-Cartan form in the adjoint representation?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, gauge-theory

While I am reading a paper, I come across a difficulty. Here, we have a Lie group and we know its Lie algebra defined as

$[G_a,G_b]=f_{ab}^{\phantom{ab}c}G_c$

with $G_a\in\mathfrak g$. Under the adjoint representation, any element of the group, called $u$ can be expressed as

$u_a^{\phantom{a} b}=[e^{\lambda^c\rho(G_c)}]_a^{\phantom{a}b}=\delta_a^b-\lambda^cf_{ca}^{\phantom{ac} b}+\frac{1}{2!}\lambda^cf_{ca}^{\phantom{ac} e}\lambda^df_{de}^{\phantom{ac} b}-\cdots$

where the representation $[\rho(G_c)]_a^{\phantom{a}b}=-f_{ca}^{\phantom{ac} b}$ is used. The the author claims that the Maurer-Cartan form is given by

$\theta=\theta^aG_a$

with

$\theta^a=-\frac{1}{2}(\gamma^{-1})^{ab}\rho(G_b)_c^{\phantom{a} d}(u^{-1})_d^{\phantom{a} e}\mathrm du_e^{\phantom{a} c}$, and $\gamma_{ab}$ is the Cartan-Killing metric.

But how to show Maurer-Cartan form takes this complicated form? Can anybody give a hint? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is yr definition of the MC form? or is it part of yr question?

Comment: No. I think there is only one definition of the MC form, right? Anyway, I mean the usual MC form.